# I installed ubuntu, booted it but things flicker and nothing happens

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I installed ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows7.

I divided new partition for it, and install went well.

However, when I tried to boot it and entering password for my account, everything flickers and nothings happens! Even menu does not show up...

Only right side thing flickers...
[image]

And nothing happens
[image]

My computer uses gigabyte b150m mainboard, so I first presumed it may be the reason of the problem. But nothing came out with it.

Comment: NVIDIA graphics?

Comment: Yeah. So I edited to the 'nomodeset' but flickering continues.